# I am not able to have one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am following examples from the internet but it's not working. The database is getting created successfully, there is no error.

What I want to have is: one user can have multiple transactions, and a transaction can have references to two users. One of those is the user who did the transaction, the second is the user to whom transaction is done.

But what is happening is I am getting three foreign keys in the Users table, but none in the Transactions table.

**See image below:**

[image: The database created image from microsoft studio management]

**My classes**

```
public class User
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Balance { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public string ProfileUrl { get; set; }

    public IList<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{ 
    public Transaction()
    {
        this.TranscationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public User FromUser { get; set; }
    public User ToUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime TranscationDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class DB: DbContext
{
    public DB() : base("name=DBConnection")
    { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does the image you posted represent your actual database schema or the intended schema? Because having the foreign keys in the `Transaction` table is correct if one User can have multiple Transactions.

Comment: It's my actual database but isn't there should be a foreign key in the user as well?

Comment: Secondly, i want to have the FromUser and ToUser as foreign key instead of creating the third one @GeorgPatscheider

Comment: `I am getting three foreign keys in the Users table, but none in the Transactions table` - **No:** according to the image you are getting three foreign keys in the *Transactions* table, and none in the *Users* table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some modification to your code.

First of all, each navigation property needs to be marked as virtual, in order to allow Entity Framework to lazy loading, unless you want always eager load all your navigations (could be a choice, is up to you).

After that, each of your user has `outgoing` and `incoming` transactions, so for the `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int Balance { get; set; }

    public string UserType { get; set; }

    public string ProfileUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Transaction> IncomingTransactions { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Transaction> OutgoingTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

Let's make virtual navigation properties of `Transaction` class

```
public class Transaction
{ 
    public Transaction()
    {
        this.TranscationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual User FromUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User ToUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime TranscationDateTime { get; set; }

}
```

Last, but not least, let's inform your DbContext of how things are supposed to go:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
   {
      base.OnModelCreating(builder);
      builder.Entity<Transaction>()
        .HasRequired<User>(t => t.FromUser)
        .WithMany(u => u.OutgoingTransactions).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
      builder.Entity<Transaction>()
        .HasRequired<User>(t => t.ToUser)
        .WithMany(u => u.IncomingTransactions).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
   }

}
```

This should be enough for EF autodiscovery to make the right assumptions and create right database structure, that would be two FKs in Transaction table each of them to the primary key of Users table.

And voilà:
[image]

Comment: Thanks this means alot. One more thing in order to keep cascading we have to put the true instead of false in WillCascadeOnDelete method? Once again thankyou

Comment: Cascading is not possible in Sql Server for both FKs pointing the same column in referenced table. It is not a limitation of EF, but of Sql Server itself. There are other solutions to achieve that, but at least one middle table is required. Speaking as a software architect, though, I would not recommed deleting users nor transactions, but use some kind of soft delete mechanism (EF can be instructed for it). You want to keep both of them, expecially money transactions :)

Answer (score 0):

> What i want to have is one user can have multiple transaction but a transaction can have reference to two user.

Your current database model reflects this accuratly. I will explain why in the rest of my answer.

The `User` table can not hold the foreign keys to the `Transactions` table because one User can be associated with multiple Transactions. If the FK column was on the User table, it would need to hold more than one TransactionId.

Instead, the references to the Users are stored in the `Transaction` table. So every Transaction only has to store a single UserId per FK column.

`Transaction.User_userId` tells us that this Transaction is in the `IList<Transaction> Transactions` of the User with the stored `User_userId`.

To get this list of Transactions for a certain user, we query

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN Users u on t.User_userId = u.userId
WHERE u.userId = {theUserId}
```

The additional FKs `ToUser_userId` and `FromUser_userId` exists because they might reference different Users.

If the semantics of the `IList<Transaction> Transactions` is actually "all transactions that originated from this User", you could configure the ModelBuilder to use the `FromUser_userId` FK for this collection instead of creating the third FK `User_userId`. See the answer of Sergey.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because EF doesn't know that one of the `FromUser` and `ToUser` fields is supposed to match the collection `Transactions` - since you are not following the [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions). You have several options on how to resolve this situation:

- If you only want to match `Transactions` collection with **either** `FromUser` or `ToUser` but not both, you can use `[ForeignKey]` and/or `[InverseProperty]` attributes to setup the database relation explicitly
- If you want to use BOTH of them, then you would need to specify **two** collections in the `User` class - e.g. `TransactionsFromUser` and `TransactionsToUser`. You might still need to setup the relationships explicitly through the attributes though